# How to setattr to instance such that self is passed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class C():
    def print_once(self):
        print(self)

def print_twice(self):
    print(self, self)

c = C()
setattr(c, 'print_twice', print_twice)
c.print_once()
c.print_twice()
```

```py
>>> <__main__.C object at 0x0000028116795108>
>>> TypeError: print_twice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'm aware `setattr(C, ..)` does the trick, but this affects future and concurrent instances of `C` and is undesired. Can `print_twice` be set only to `c`, such that `self` is passed automatically just like to `print_once`?

Comment: Is `print_twice` inside class `C`?

Comment: `setattr(c, 'print_twice', functools.partial(print_twice, c))` would emulate what an actual bound method does.

Comment: The mechanism of passing ``self`` is related to the descriptor protocol – the TLDR is that methods *must be* on the class, by definition. A function on an instance is just a callable attribute.  Why do you even *want* ``self`` to be passed automatically? ``self`` will always be ``c``, so why not do ``c.print_twice = functools.partial(print_twice, c)``? How is this related to ``setattr`` in specific? ``c.print_twice = print_twice`` would be equivalent to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28060251/10133797):

```py
class C():
    def print_once(self):
        print(self)

def print_twice(self):
    print(self, self)

c = C()
setattr(c, 'print_twice', print_twice.__get__(c))
c.print_once()
c.print_twice()
```

```py
>> <__main__.C object at 0x000002122DE7FDC8>
>> <__main__.C object at 0x000002122DE7FDC8> <__main__.C object at 0x000002122DE7FDC8>
```